# RESTful server seems not working properly

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I'm using NetBeans and I want to run a local server, as described in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/apache-cxf-rest-api
The problem is the following: i run the server endpoint and then i run the tests and i get the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/course/courses/1
at tests.RestTest.getCourse(RestTest.java:50)
at tests.RestTest.firstTest(RestTest.java:67)
```

Now, the server manage just a list of courses and students who attempts the courses. The server endpoint's code is the following:

```
public class RestfulServer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String address = "http://localhost:8080/";
        System.out.println("Initializing server...");
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factoryBean = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setResourceClasses(CourseRepository.class);
        factoryBean.setResourceProvider(new SingletonResourceProvider(new CourseRepository()));
        factoryBean.setAddress(address);
        System.out.println("Server address is " + address);
        Server server = factoryBean.create();
        System.out.println("Server running...");
    }
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
public class RestTest {

    private static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/course/courses/";
    private static CloseableHttpClient client;

    public RestTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws IOException {
        client.close();
    }

    private Course getCourse(int courseOrder) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + courseOrder);
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        Course course
          = JAXB.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(input), Course.class);
        return course;
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() throws IOException{
        Assert.assertEquals("REST with Spring", getCourse(1).getName());
    }
}
```

I suppose you would like to know where this methods go, so this is the CourseRepository class, where it the local database (just a bunch of strings) and the @GET, @PUT etc. methods.

```
@Path("course")
@Produces("text/html")
public class CourseRepository {
    private Map<Integer, Course> courses = new HashMap<>();

    //other things not useful now...

private Course findById(int id) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Course> course : courses.entrySet()) {
        if (course.getKey() == id) {
            return course.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@GET
@Path("courses/{courseId}")
public Course getCourse(@PathParam("courseId") int courseId) {
    return findById(courseId);
}
```

Now, the thing I do not understand is why i get the previous error while running tests. It is like I typed the wrong URL, but I'm not sure about it.

Edit:
In order to answer JB Nizet, i tryed to debug the server and then to encapsulate

```
return findById(courseId);
```

in a try/catch statement, since it seemed that it was that method to cause the execption. Although, the "catch" didn't catch anything at all, even if the execption appears right after the execution of the method. Additionally, i noticed just now a new warning appearing in the server output window:

```
AVVERTENZA: Both com.bankrestserver.CourseRepository#getCourse and com.bankrestserver.CourseRepository#getCourse are equal candidates for handling the current request which can lead to unpredictable results
ago 25, 2019 12:15:36 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem

GRAVE: No message body writer has been found for class com.bankrestserver.Course, ContentType: text/html
```

Comment: 500 means that the server had a problem. So your findById() method probably throws an exception. Do you have any error in your server logs? Have you tried debugging the code, or at least adding println statements to know what happens? Is the getCourse()method even called?

Comment: Yes, I did. It seems that the exception is thrown by
InputStream input = url.openStream();
in the RestTest class. Although, the exception printed is the same.

Comment: What you need to debug is the *server*. Not the client.